# How to get a response from Moodle when a student start a course or completes a course?

Tags: moodle

Each time  student starts a course or completes a course, i need to update my system indicating that the course is started or completed depending on the response from moodle. How can I achieve this in moodle

Answer (score 0):

You can use event observers in moodle. Observe the events you mentioned and perform the action required.
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2#Event_observers